# Как сохранить все строки из datagridview с картинкой?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть datagridview, в нее можно записать название, описание... и картинку, как можно сохранить все данные и картинку для будущего открытия?

Comment: В бд можно сохранять

Comment: Можно сериализовать в файл.

Comment: Представь, что каждая строка - класс, а столбец - свойство этого класса. Можешь пробежать по всем строкам dgv и создавать экземпляр класса, передавая в конструктор значения под конкретными столбцами. Либо, если чуть сложнее, можно воспользоваться рефлексией. Далее, получив List<T> (где T - твой класс), сохраняешь эти значения в базу данных или, например, json (почитай про серилизацию). Касаемо картинки - можешь конвертировать её в base64 формат и хранить её в виде строки в базе данных. Когда будешь её оттуда доставать, конвертируй обратно в Bitmap